# "normal" number of processes/threads

Tags: apache-2.2, ps

Considering a standard LAMP server (aka webhosting) what should be a limit at number of processes/thread?

```
ps -elfT | wc -l  
475
```

"Limit" I mean: on DDOS probably the numbers of children-processes of httpd will increase quickly.

Comment: If your goal is defends your webserver, you'd better looking for about IDS like psad or similar.